# Down-sets of a finite ordered set are down Max.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, first-order-logic, order-theory, lattice-orders

The following exercise comes from the book: *Introduction to Lattices and order (second edition, B. A. Davey, H.A. Priestley)*.

### Problem 1.14, pag. 27.

Let $P$ be a finite oredered set.

(1) Show that $Q=\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)$, for all $Q\in\mathcal{O}(P)$;

(2) Establish a one-to-one correspondence between the elemenents of $\mathcal{O}(P)$ and antichain in $P$.

(3) Hence show that, for all $x\in P$,

$$|\mathcal{O}(P)|=|\mathcal{O}(P\setminus\{x\})|+|\mathcal{O}(P\setminus (\downarrow x\ \cup \ \uparrow x))|$$

**Some definitions**

*Definition 1* (**antichain**). Let $P$ an ordered set. $P$ is an antichain if $x\le y$ in $P$ only if $x=y$.

*Definition 2* (**maximal element**). Let $P$ an ordered set, $Q\subseteq P$. Then $a\in Q$ is a maximal element of $Q$ if $a\le x$ and $x\in Q$ imply $a=x$. The set of all maximal element of $Q$ is $\mbox{Max}(Q)$.

*Definition 3* (**Down-set**). Let $P$ be an ordered set, and $Q\subseteq P$. $Q$ is a down-set (of $P$) if, whenever $x\in Q,y\in P$ and $y\le x$, we have $y\in Q$.

*Definition 4* (**down Q, down x, up x**). Given an arbitrary subset $Q$ of $P$ and $x\in P$, we define

$\\ \bullet \ \downarrow Q=\{y\in P \ | \ \exists x\in Q\ \mbox{s.t.} \ y\le x\} \ \ \ (\mbox{Down} \ Q)$

$\bullet \ \downarrow x=\{y\in P\ | \ y\le x\} \ \ \ (\mbox{Down} \ x)$

$\bullet \ \uparrow x=\{y\in P\ | \ y\ge x\}\ \ \ (\mbox{Up} \ x)$

*Definition 5* (**set of all down-set of P**). The family of all down-set of a set $P$ is denoted by $\mathcal{O}(P)$.

$|A|$ is the cardinality of the set $A$.

### My ideas

(1.a) I want to show that $\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)\subseteq Q,\, \forall Q\in\mathcal{O}(P)$.

Let $x\in\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)$, then $\exists q\in\mbox{Max}(Q)$ such that $x\le q\implies x\in Q$, because $Q$ is a down-set of $P$. Is it ok?

(1.b) Now I'll try to prove that $Q\subseteq\downarrow \mbox{Max}(Q)$.

Suppose, by contraddiction, that there exists $q\in Q\setminus\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)$, i.e. $q\in Q\wedge q\notin\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)$, so $\forall s\in\mbox{Max}(Q)$, we have that $(q>s)\vee q\ ||\ s$ ($q$ is not comparable with $s$).

If $q>s$, then $s\notin\mbox{Max}(Q)$, (contraddiction).

If $q\ || \ s$, then $q\in\mbox{Max}(Q)\implies q\in\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)$ (contraddiction).

Is this part ok?

(2) Let $\mathcal{A}(P)$ be the set of all antichains of $P$. I think that

$\begin{array}{ccccc}\phi&:&\mathcal{O}(P)&\longrightarrow&\mathcal{A}(P)\\ \\ &&Q=\downarrow\mbox{Max}(Q)&\longmapsto&\phi(Q)=\mbox{Max}(Q)\end{array}$

is a good one-to-one correspondence.

(3) I have no idea to solve this. I have to study [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457685/number-of-antichains-and-number-of-downsets)  to understand what to do.

Please, check my ideas and tell me if they are ok or not: the order theory is so insidous to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) is OK, although the proof that $Q \subseteq {\downarrow}\mathrm{Max}Q$ has at least a minor problem: if $q||s$ for all $s \in \mathrm{Max}Q$, then $q \notin \mathrm{Max}Q$, because $q \leq q$.
But you can just say (I guess) that in a finite poset any element is below a maximal element, and proceed from there.

(2) is OK.

For (3), just note that the number of anti-chains in $P$ is the sum of the number of anti-chains in $P\setminus\{x\}$ with the number of anti-chains in $P \setminus ({\downarrow}x \cup {\uparrow}x)$.
Indeed, if $A$ is an anti-chain in $P$ and $x \in P$, then, if $x \in A$ it follows that $A$ is an anti-chain in $P \setminus ({\downarrow}x \cup {\uparrow}x)$;
otherwise (if $x \notin A$), then $A$ is an anti-chain in $P \setminus\{x\}$.
Hence, by (2) you get the desired result.

Comment: Thanks you! I need to writer the 1.b in a batter way. (3) Is clear now. I really appreciate Your help. Anyway, I think there Is a minor typo in your answer: $a\in P$ Is clearly $x\in P$ in (3). Thanks for Your time.

Comment: @Ixion Thanks! Corrected the typo.