# Order ideals of a fence

Tags: order-theory, fibonacci-numbers, lattice-orders

Let $F_n$ be the $n$-element fence, that is, $F_n=\{a_1, \ldots, a_n\}$ with
$$a_1>a_2<a_3>\cdots a_n$$
and no other elements related.
Here is the Wikipedia article about fences : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fence_(mathematics).

The Fibonacci sequence is given by $f_1=f_2=1$ and $f_k=f_{k-2}+f_{k-1}$, for $k>2$.
The first few numbers are
$$1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,\ldots$$
Show that the number of order-ideals (down-sets) of $F_n$ is $f_{n+2}$.

It is easy to see that $F_1$ has two order-ideals: $\varnothing$ and $\{a_1\}$;
$F_2$ is a two element chain $a_1>a_2$ and has three order-ideals: $\varnothing$, $\{a_2\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2\}$, and so on.

How can I prove this in general?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use induction on the number of elements.
For the induction step, use [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457685/number-of-antichains-and-number-of-downsets) and the fact that
$$F_n\setminus\{a_n\}\cong F_{n-1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
F_n\setminus({\uparrow}a_n \cup {\downarrow}a_n) \cong F_{n-2}.$$

Comment: I understand. Now I will make my own answer with the details. Thanks

Comment: @Hugo Ok, that may be a good exercise!

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{O}(P)$ be the set of order-ideals of the poset $P$.
Since $|F_1|=1$, it is $|\mathcal{O}(F_1)|=2=f_3$.
Suppose that $|\mathcal{O}(F_k)|=f_{k+2}$ for all $k<n$.
Since
$$F_n\setminus\{a_n\}\cong F_{n-1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
F_n\setminus({\uparrow}a_n \cup {\downarrow}a_n) \cong F_{n-2}$$
which can be easily verified by eye inspection using the diagrams,
by induction and [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/457685/number-of-antichains-and-number-of-downsets)
$$|\mathcal{O}(F_n)|=|\mathcal{O}(F_{n-1})|+|\mathcal{O}(F_{n-2})|=f_{n+1}+f_n=f_{n+2}.$$

Comment: In the first line, where you have $|\mathcal O(P)|=2=f_3$, it's $\mathcal O(F_1)$.

Comment: @amrsa Thanks. Fixed.